# How to set Expiration Time Rule on PutS3Object Processor in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

As of writing, the NiFi documentation for the PutS3Object processor doesn't say how to properly set the "Expiration Time Rule" property.

Has any successfully set this?  What are the units, etc.?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field is expecting the name of a bucket Lifecycle Rule.  This can be seen in the S3 console properties for the bucket, under Management, Lifecycle, "Lifecycle rule" in the table.  The code used to set this on the request is [ObjectMetadata.setExpirationTimeRuleId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#setExpirationTimeRuleId-java.lang.String-).

Comment: So the User can only point at a Lifecycle Rule that has been previously-created in the AWS S3 Management dashboard?  FWIW, I'm trying to understand if I can programmatically set the object that I'm putting on S3 to expire at a given date.

Comment: I do not believe you can set a specific expiration date on an individual object.  NiFi does not have controls for this, and I do not believe S3 supports it either.  Have you tried looking at equivalent settings for the AWS CLI?

Comment: Not the CLI, but the web UI has an option for tags ... since the NiFi property notes that it supports NiFi expression language, I thought there might be a way to use a FlowFile attribute as a tag for the Lifecycle Rule.

Comment: You could use expression language to set the Lifecycle Rule Id.  I'm afraid PutS3Object does not yet support S3 tags, as far as I know.